# Run project with Spark and maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, tinkerpop-blueprint

I'm trying to run my class java that read a GML file and I use Tinkerpop and GMLReader for that , the problem is when I try to run it with spark it gives me an exception
I wrote a simple code for testing :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    TinkerGraph graphs = new TinkerGraph();
    String in = "/home/salma/Desktop/celegansneural.gml";
    GMLReader.inputGraph(graphs, in);
    System.out.println(graphs);
 }
```

The command that I'm using to run the class :

```
root@salma-SATELLITE-C855-1EQ:/usr/local/spark# ./bin/spark-submit --class graph_example.WordCount --master local[2] ~/workspace/graph_example/target/graph_example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 com/tinkerpop/blueprints/impls/tg/TinkerGraph
        at graph_example.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.tg.TinkerGraph
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 10 more
     Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the dependency containing the TinkerGraph implementation.
If I'm not mistaken, you need to provide [this jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blueprints-core/2.6.0/blueprints-core-2.6.0.jar)

Then you run `spark-submit` as usual but with `--jars /some/location/blueprints-core-2.6.0.jar`

It is explained in the [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) :

> When using spark-submit, the application jar along with any jars
>   included with the --jars option will be automatically transferred to
>   the cluster.

Comment: It works thanx (y)